# RxJS - An observable 'A' doesn't stop emitting with a takeUntil that is piped from the same observable 'A'

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, takeuntil

I have an observable that prints a number to the console every second after a start button is clicked. The observable should stop printing 5 seconds after the start button is clicked.

**Start Condition**
every second after the start button is clicked

**End Condition**
five seconds after the start button is clicked

**The code that doesn't work**

```
const startClick$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('start'), 'click');
const stop$ = startClick$.pipe(switchMapTo(interval(5000)));
const printInterval$ = interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(stop$));
const startPrint$ = startClick$.pipe(switchMapTo(printInterval$));

startPrint$.subscribe(
  value => {
    console.log('new value is:', value);
  },
  () => {
    console.log('there was some error!');
  },
  () => {
    console.log('i have completed');
  }
);

stop$.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('i should stop right now!!');
});
```

After five seconds elapse after clicking the start button, the startPrint$ Observable does not stop emitting.

**The code that works**

```
const endClick$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('end'), 'click');
const stopWithEndClick$ = endClick$.pipe(switchMapTo(interval(5000)));
const printInterval1$ = interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(stopWithEndClick$));
const startPrint1$ = startClick$.pipe(switchMapTo(printInterval1$));

startPrint1$.subscribe(
  value => {
    console.log('1: new value is:', value);
  },
  () => {
    console.log('1: there was some error!');
  },
  () => {
    console.log('1: i have completed');
  }
);

stopWithEndClick$.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('1: i should stop right now!!');
});
```

Here i have another button `end`, and i takeUntil 5 seconds after the end button is clicked. In this case the observable stops emitting as expected.

How can i make the first case work, am I making any mistakes here? the entire working code can be found at https://stackblitz.com/edit/take-until-issue?file=index.ts

Comment: ``` const printInterval$ = interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(stop$)); ``` this line have an strange operation, do not work. If you modify to use takeUntil like this ``` startPrint$.pipe(takeUntil(stop$)) ``` in final subscription its works perfectly as other modifications of your chain.

Comment: wouldn't this just complete the outer observable after five seconds? I want to print a number on the console each second after the start button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the order of subscriptions inside RxJS operators. When you first click the "start" button, the first who receives the notification is `stop$` but none is listening to `stop$` so the notification doesn't trigger anything. You're seeing `"'i should stop right now!!'` only because you subscribe yourself at the end.

So the easiest solution is creating the `stop$` chain as an Observable that will start emitting only after you subscribe like `timer(5000)` that emits just once and then completes.

```
const stop$ = timer(5000);
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/take-until-issue-or4okm?file=index.ts

Just be aware, that you might get different number of results because RxJS (JavaScript in general) can't guarantee that `5000ms` is going to be exactly `5000ms`. The same applies to `1000ms` so sometimes the events might be triggered in a different order. Better use for example `take(5)` if you want only 5 results. Also for logging it's better to use for example `tap(v => console.log(v))` so you won't make a another subscription.

Comment: I have a question here, the observable timer(5000) would emit after 5 seconds, however,  my requirement is to start the timer only after the start button is clicked. How would i achieve that? Also, when i do ```const stop$ = startClick$.pipe(switchMapTo(interval(5000)));
``` don't i create a subscription to startClick$ anyway?

Comment: You don't create a subscription until you subscribe with eg. `subscribe()` call. So `timer(5000)` didn't start the timer because noone is subscribed yet. The same is with `startClick$.pipe(switchMapTo(interval(5000)))` - this doesn't create a subscription.

Comment: Martin, thanks for taking the timeout to reply. However, i am still confused.

1. How does the code work if i pipe the stop interval from another button instead of the same button, please refer to the code section under the heading `The code that works`
2. How would i create an observable, that only emits 5 seconds after the start button is pressed.

Comment: @uMar.. This is the first scenario I described above where `start$` emits but noone has subscribed to `stop$` so the `inverval` Observable never starts.

Comment: Just looked at the source code and understood what you were saying. Thanks for the explanation !